# Read OData aggregated properties in C#

Tags: c#, .net, group-by, odata

I'm using ODATA Azure DevOps API and doing a simple query to find all the task those are completed in user story. To get this result in C#, we are using ODATA Connected service V4 from NuGet.

Query

```
https://AzureDEvOpsURL/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItems?
$filter=WorkItemType eq 'User Story'&$Select=WorkItemId
&$expand=Descendants($apply=filter(WorkItemType eq 'Task' and state eq 'Closed')/aggregate($count as CompletedTasks))
```

Result

```
"value":[{"WorkItemId":53317,"Descendants":[{"@odata.id":null,"CompletedTasks":4}]}]
```

How can we read CompletedTasks in C#? Is there a way to read the computed properties for example

> CompletedTasks

any help is welcome?

MyCode

> DataServiceQuery queryUserStories = ODataAPI.WorkItems
> .AddQueryOption("$filter", "WorkItemType eq 'User Story'")
> .AddQueryOption("$select", "WorkItemId")
> .AddQueryOption("$expand", "Descendants($apply=filter(WorkItemType eq 'Task' and state eq
> 'Closed')/aggregate($count as CompletedTasks))");

foreach (var WIT in queryUserStories) {...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OData client's DataServiceQuery currently does not provide any method for reading data from an aggregation or groupby request. There's ongoing work to add support for that (https://github.com/OData/odata.net/pull/1810). But until then, I believe your best alternative is to make the request directly to the service then to use a JSON serializer like System.Text.Json to deserialize the response.